# How/why can Firefox packages work on all Linuxes?

Tags: compiling, firefox, linux-kernel, gcc, glibc

How/why can a Firefox 64bit (or 32bit) [package](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-US/) work on different Linux distributions since each Linux distribution has a different version for gcc, glibc, linux kernel, etc. ?

Comment: I assume it is coded in a certain way as to detect which version of what you have and build itself accordingly.

Comment: @MaxMackie Not really, the package is already built; it is a binary package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it's coded the application is not using any calls that would limit it on any particular distribution.  Having said that the statement you are making is completely false because unless `libstdc++.so.6`, `libm.so.6`, `libc.so.6` are present on the system `firefox` will not work.  So your question is predicated on `gcc` and `glibc` being at least at the particular minimum versions.

Comment: So basically, Firefox is compiled using pretty old applications so it will work on any Linux distro. This is because glibc, gcc, etc. are considerably backwards compatible.

Comment: Not old just compatible. There are certain features of gcc which are not compatible from 3.x to 4.x